# SQL Server 2012 - Can't connect to local instance

Tags: sql-server

I am having trouble connection to a local instance of Microsoft SQL Server 2012, this is what i have tried so far:

**SQL Server Configuration Manager**

- Enable TCP/IP
- Enable Named Pipes
- Enable Shared Memory

The SQL Server, SQL Server Browser and SQL Server Agent services are all running.

I have verified that there is a SQL Server instance with: `sqlcmd.exe -L` this command gives me the following:

```
Servers:
    (local)
    MON-W530
```

**SQLCMD**

`sqlcmd.exe -S MON-W530\MSSQLSERVER -E` Gives the following output:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

**OSQL**

`OSQL.EXE -S MON-W530\MSSQLSERVER -E` Gives the following output (Identical to sqlcmd.exe above)

```
[SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87].
[SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired
[SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
```

Its a fresh installation of Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition, any help is appriciated.

**Edit**

Using SQL Server Management Studio 2012, i don't have the option to specify username and password for Windows Authentication, so i guess its not enabled, any clues on enabling Windows Auth is also appriciated.

Comment: can you try connecting with `sqlcmd -S . -E`? The instance name you specify looks like a "default" instance which doesn't have a name when connecting.

Comment: `sqlcmd -S . -E` Output: Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login failed for user 'DomainNameRemoved\mon'..

Comment: From http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx : `Using Configuration Manager, in the left  pane select SQL Server Services. In the right-pane  confirm that the instance of the Database Engine is present and running. The instance named MSSQLSERVER is a default (unnamed) instance. There can only be one default instance. Other (named) instances will have their names listed between the parentheses.` SQL Server Configuration Manager lists the server as: SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) i guess the instance is named

Comment: What is edition of SQL Server you installed, is it express edition. A silly question but have you made sure you hve installed database engine feature

Comment: From the SQL Server log: `Login failed for user 'DomainNameRemoved\mon'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided.`

Comment: @Shanky: Its Developer Edition, i have not done the installation my self, so i dont know, how do i check that the Database Engine feature is installed?

Comment: Ok going by login failure message can you make sure login ''DomainNameRemoved\mon'' is added into SQL server login

Comment: @Shanky: I dont know how to do that, i can't connect to the database?

Comment: Please take help of person who has installed it. May be he can login and add your account. If you cannot get hold of person who installed and you are administrator on windows machine use this http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2465/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-if-you-are-completely-locked-out/  to create a login, grant it privileges, and then login